# Label will display but not text_field - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, form-for

I'm working on my first rails app and having a weird issue.
I'm using Rails 3.2.6 with mongodb.

In my view, I can get a label to display like so:

```
<%= f.label :percent  %>
```

But when I try the same thing with a text field 
like so:

```
<%= f.text_field :percent  %>
```

the page doesn't even load, nothing happens.

Here is my controller:

```
class TrimmingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @order = Order.find params[:order_id]
end
```

And my model:

```
class Trimming
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :order

  field :percent, type: String

end
```

And here is my whole view:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
<p>
     <%= f.text_field :percent  %>  
</p>
<% end %>
```

I just want to get a text_field to display sorry for the
simpleton question but I've been trying for 2 days to get
this text field to pop up.

Comment: if you say that nothing happens if you try to load the page, have you checked the logs? maybe some hints are there.Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: a ha! Yeah I got error: `Error (undefined method `percent' for #<Order _id:` so defining percent in model is not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make percent attr_accessible. Add this to your model.

```
attr_accessible: :percent
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it with following code in view:
`<%= form_for :order do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :percent  %>

<% end %>`